# Java jstack sample pointing at closing bracket rather than line of code

Tags: java, jstack

I am attempting to debug a performance problem within Hadoop, and as part of that I have captured jstacks on a few occasions from different hadoop builds and running on different Java versions. When my performance problem manifests, I get a jstack of the runnable thread like this:

```
"DataXceiver for client DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-619388227_1 at /x.x.x.x:35518 [Sending block BP-1509854702-x.x.x.x-1392815592442:blk_3738093208_1102227094469]" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f1a683cf800 nid=0xb61d1 runnable [0x00007f1a36060000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.util.FoldedTreeSet.get(FoldedTreeSet.java:449)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.impl.ReplicaMap.get(ReplicaMap.java:111)
    - locked <0x0000000751682590> (a org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.impl.FsDatasetImpl)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.impl.ReplicaMap.get(ReplicaMap.java:89)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.impl.FsDatasetImpl.getVolume(FsDatasetImpl.java:177)
    - locked <0x0000000751682590> (a org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.impl.FsDatasetImpl)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.impl.FsDatasetImpl.getVolume(FsDatasetImpl.java:127)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BlockSender.<init>(BlockSender.java:283)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataXceiver.readBlock(DataXceiver.java:537)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.Receiver.opReadBlock(Receiver.java:148)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.Receiver.processOp(Receiver.java:103)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataXceiver.run(DataXceiver.java:246)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

If I check the source code line 449 at the top of the stack is part of this method and it is always on the closing curly brace highlighted. Every time this problem occurs the stack trace is the same and I have seen it on Java 7 and Java 8.

```
public E get(Object obj, Comparator<?> cmp) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(obj);

    Node<E> node = root;
    while (node != null) {
      E[] entries = node.entries;

      int leftIndex = node.leftIndex;
      int result = compare(obj, entries[leftIndex], cmp);
      if (result < 0) {
        node = node.left;
      } else if (result == 0) {
        return entries[leftIndex];
      } else {
        int rightIndex = node.rightIndex;
        if (leftIndex != rightIndex) {
          result = compare(obj, entries[rightIndex], cmp);
        }
        if (result == 0) {
          return entries[rightIndex];
        } else if (result > 0) {
          node = node.right;
        } else {
          int low = leftIndex + 1;
          int high = rightIndex - 1;
          while (low <= high) {
            int mid = (low + high) >>> 1;
            result = compare(obj, entries[mid], cmp);
            if (result > 0) {
              low = mid + 1;
            } else if (result < 0) {
              high = mid - 1;
            } else {
              return entries[mid];
            }
          }
          return null;
        }
      }
    } // *** This is line 449 which the jstack always has at the top of the stack.
    return null;
  }
```

I have other jstack samples from the same class where the line numbers look correct, and hence I don't think I am looking at the wrong version of this class. The jstack has definitely been captured with the jstack command from the same Java home as by the same user as the running process. Everything else about the samples look correct.

Can anyone offer any reasons as to why jstack always shows a closing brace as the runnable line? I have never seen that before looking at many jstacks outputs.

### UPDATE

Investigating the suggestion that this is caused by a miss-match in compiled and source code, I found another stack sample from the same process as above:

```
"Thread-41" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0000000003c39000 nid=0x1c6fe1 runnable [0x00007f1a4b7b8000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.util.FoldedTreeSet.removeAndGet(FoldedTreeSet.java:879)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.util.FoldedTreeSet.removeAndGet(FoldedTreeSet.java:892)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.impl.ReplicaMap.remove(ReplicaMap.java:162)
    - locked <0x0000000751682590> (a org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.impl.FsDatasetImpl)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.impl.FsDatasetImpl.invalidate(FsDatasetImpl.java:2021)
    - locked <0x0000000751682590> (a org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.impl.FsDatasetImpl)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPOfferService.processCommandFromActive(BPOfferService.java:686)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPOfferService.processCommandFromActor(BPOfferService.java:632)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPServiceActor.processCommand(BPServiceActor.java:729)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPServiceActor.offerService(BPServiceActor.java:539)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPServiceActor.run(BPServiceActor.java:695)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

This is in a different method in the same class, but the code in the removeAndGet method is very similar to that in get. Here are the relevant code snippets:

```
  public E removeAndGet(Object obj) {
    return removeAndGet(obj, comparator); // *** This is 892, this is correct as per the stack trace above
  }
```

```
  public E removeAndGet(Object obj, Comparator<?> cmp) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(obj);

    if (!isEmpty()) {
      Node<E> node = root;
      while (node != null) {
        E[] entries = node.entries;
        int leftIndex = node.leftIndex;
        int result = compare(obj, entries[leftIndex], cmp);
        if (result < 0) {
          node = node.left;
        } else if (result == 0) {
          return removeElementLeft(node);
        } else {
          int rightIndex = node.rightIndex;
          if (leftIndex != rightIndex) {
            result = compare(obj, entries[rightIndex], cmp);
          }
          if (result == 0) {
            return removeElementRight(node);
          } else if (result > 0) {
            node = node.right;
          } else {
            int low = leftIndex + 1, high = rightIndex - 1;
            while (low <= high) {
              int mid = (low + high) >>> 1;
              result = compare(obj, entries[mid], cmp);
              if (result > 0) {
                low = mid + 1;
              } else if (result == 0) {
                return removeElementAt(node, mid);
              } else {
                high = mid - 1;
              }
            }
            return null;
          }
        }
      } // **** This is 879 - again the same as the get method
    }
    return null;
  }
```

The code just a bit later in the source file appears correct, but this strangely points at a curly bracket again.

Answer (score 0):

This happens in 99% of the cases when your source code and compiled class are not the same. I.e. compiled class is compiled from a different source (newer or older version). Thry to de-compile your class (produce .java from .class) See if it helps

Comment: I thought the same so I looked into hadoop's github and this class doesn't seem to have been modified since the version it's been introduced in, [release-3.0.0-RC0](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/release-3.0.0-RC0/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/util/FoldedTreeSet.java#L449)

Comment: I would then try to de-compile the .class. Maybe they published the source that is not correct. A single line addition or removal would cause this problem. So, the published source may be logically the same but contains some more or less blank lines...

Comment: Yea, this code has basically never been changed so far as I can tell too, and other samples that hit different lines in that class are correct, as are all other lines in other classes. All produced using the same build process. We use jstacks quite a bit debugging hadoop problems and this stack is the only time I have seen this. I will see if I can decompile a built version ...

Comment: I extracted the class from the jar and opened the class in Intellij, but its not helpful as all the comments are stripped out and the class has a couple of nested classes, so the lines are all shifted. I did however scan my stack traces and found another method in this class, which has very similar code and where the exact same problem occurs. Therefore I think something else is going on here and not a miss-match in source and compiled code. More details added to the original description.